# Inheritance/Composition because of simple class variations

Tags: c#, oop

I have one base class called "Message" in my code.

Now I need some variations of that class like "AudibleMessage" that adds and audio configuration class, or "AutomaticMessage" that adds some configuration to skip the message automaticly.

I realized that maybe "AudibleMessage" wants the "AutomaticMessage" additions too. So I have a complex inheritance/ class structure /functinonality problem.

I tried inheritance and composition but I don't really like any of the solutions I came around. Also, I think I may be overthinking what to do and I just have to decide one: inheritance or composition.

```cs
public class Message
{
   public string title;
   public string content;
}

public class AudibleMessage : Message
{
   public AudioConfiguration audioConfiguration;
}

public class AutomaticMessage : Message
{
   public MessageAutomatization messageAutomatization;
}
```

My conclusion is to have multiple classes with the same variables but needed because of their different functionality or lots of inherited/composed classes with excessive coupling.

Thank you all.

Comment: Neither inheritance nor composition is about data, but about *behavior*. You have to have *behavior* in your classes for either of those things to make any sense.

Comment: Exactly as Robert states in my answer I assume some sort of behavior in the configuration to include a method that deals with the specific additional information added through said configuration.

Comment: Hi Adán, was my answer useful to you?
If yes would you mind accepting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go with a solution where I have a base Message class as you have and then I would have a Message class with a configuration interface property.
Then I would have the configuration have concrete implementations.

That way you could include methods that all configurations should have in the interface.
In the concrete implementations you could then specify all the extra data and methods to use.

```cs
public class Message
{
   public string title;
   public string content;
}

public class ConfiguredMessage : Message 
{
   IMessageConfiguration configuration { get; set; }
}

public interface IMessageConfiguration
{
   void readMessage();
}

public class AudibleMessageConfiguration: IMessageConfiguration
{
   public void ReadMessage()
   {
      // play audio message on speaker?
   }
   public AudioConfiguration audioConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class AutomaticMessageConfiguration : IMessageConfiguration
{
   public void ReadMessage()
   {
      // execute automated actions?
   }
   public MessageAutomatization messageAutomatization { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it is useful and if there are any misunderstandings or mistakes in my logic please let me know.